# Missing music after failed renaming with eyeD3

Tags: bash, filesystems, filenames

Most of my music is missing after I attempted to organize my music library with eyeD3.

eyeD3 has a function described as thus:

```
--rename=PATTERN
 Rename the file based on PATTERN which may contain the following substitution  variables: %A (artist), %a (album), %t (title), %n (track number), and %N (the total track count). The PATTERN string MUST not contain the file name extension.
```

I ran this line of code:

```
$ eyeD3 --rename=./%t ./*
```

I tried running this too:

```
$ eyeD3 --rename=./%t *
```

My current working directory was /media/Music, where /media is a partition on my hard drive. All of the music from my Music folder is now missing except for: one song within each sub-folder, songs not within a sub-folder, and any songs with a .flac extension.

I had about 1000 songs. The operation was quick, and I do not think the songs could have been moved outside the partition or written over in the short amount of time. What happened? How can I get my music back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, could it be that your songs did not have a valid id3 tag? In that case, each song would be renamed to unknown.mp3 or trackX.mp3. If all songs had the same (missing) track name in their id3 tag then the command you used would sequentially rename each of them to the same name, overwriting each file in the process. The end result would be one file in each folder which would be the last track renamed.

If that is the case I don't know any easy way to get your music back. In case that is not what happened, try running this command:

```
ls -la /media/Music
```

That will list all files, including hidden ones.

Comment: Sorry, my data was inaccurate, but you did solve the problem, thanks. I think I did run a line with %A. Each song in the folders had the same artist thus naming them all the same. The songs not in any subfolders were of mismatched artists and were not given the same name. later when I ran eyeD3 --rename=./%t * the remaining files were renamed to the title of the song.

Comment: Ouch, sorry about that then. Losing a music collection hurts...

Comment: The worst part- I can't just download it again. My internet downloading is limited. I'm going to try and see if I can use a tool called scalpel to get my music back